# Is there a way to set a Windows environment variable in the current environment?

Tags: windows, variables, set, environment, setx

setx does not set variables in the current environment. I want to set an environment variable and immediately use it. Can this be done?  thx.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  What do you mean by "current environment?"

Comment: If you're talking about a command shell or batch script, use the `set` command.  From a Win32 application, use `SetEnvironmentVariable`.  Some language runtimes may also have their own set of environment variables, you will need to be more specific.